# How to prove an avocado grown from a seed is not a Hass?

Tags: germination, propagation, avocado, cuttings

I understand that

1. In order for a Hass avocado to be so called, it needs to be
   grown from a cutting - specifically growing it from a seed will not
   result in a Hass avocado.
2. Avocados grown from seed take many
   years longer to fruit then avocados grown from cuttings from mature
   trees.
3. That having multiple Hass trees will not aid in cross pollination, Really  an A and a B type are required for ideal pollination [ unless you have very variable weather like in NZ causing a period of overlap, where the tree can pollinate itself ]

If I'm right is anyone able to point me to authoritative source (preferably online) of this information, or, if not, can you set me straight?  The specific reason I'm asking is that someone I believe to be a charlatan is advertising exhorbitant "non-hass" trees as Hass, and refusing to correct his advertisement and I would like to "force his hand" so that the naive people he is targetting are not bitten after tending a plant for 4 years...

Comment: Avocado cultivars should grow true from seed *provided the seed was not cross pollinated by a different cultivar.* Cuttings are guaranteed to grow true to type. So unless you can *prove* these seeds may have been cross pollinated, you probably don't have much of a legal case against the guy. If a *commercial* avocado grower was dumb enough to buy seed-grown plants from an unknown source - well, they should have known better IMO.

Comment: @alephzero: autoimpollination is not enough. With pollination from same plant, you will have different DNA. If you had gene Aa, the resulting plant could have AA, Aa, and aa, so totally different cultivar. Clones needs to be cloned. For seed cultivars, the genes should be stables.

Comment: it sounds like you  bought an avocado seed from a hass avocado, therefore it is a hass avocado seed, and has the same type of genetics. It's just like an apple tree, the seeds don't come true, but it is still the same species.